# Hibernate - Saving Entities - Update Table - Not based on Primary Key

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, persistence

Pseudo code to get to the point:

```
@Entity
Person {
   @Id
   Integer id;
   String SSN;
   String name;
}
```

Use case for repository, or service:

```
personRepository.save(new Person(ssn:"123456", name:"jeff")):
```

- id is unique and autoincremented primary key
- SSN is unique and is the identifier of a person
- name is just a string and could be changed

Currently save uses hibernate's `merge()` to do the insert/update, but I don't have the `id` when I'm saving (part of my abstraction layer so that client code doesn't need to touch entities at all), so how can I update the persons name if the SSN is already present in the database without having to do a separate lookup on that field, and then branch logic in there (I don't want to do that because I may be updating and inserting MANY people at once and think it will be slow)

Comment: should I just delete all and then re-insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I update the persons name if the SSN is already present in the database without having to do a separate lookup on that field, and then branch logic in there (...)

The only option I can think would be to use the SSN as primary key.

Answer (score 2):

You could use your session to generate a HQL query, and roll your own update along the lines of:

```
String queryString = "update Person set name = :name where ssn = :ssn";
Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
query.setString("name", newName);
query.setString("ssn", ssn);
query.executeUpdate();
```

I'm not aware of a way to just update an entity as you are suggesting, as Hibernate very heavily depends on your @Id field to aid in determining persisted state.

Comment: Is there any way to make this the default update for an entity?  Because I will not always be calling update manually, it could cascade from a parent object.  If not, this is likely the best I can do, however I will likely re-evaluate my Entities and come up with something differnt

Comment: If the object is properly associated with a parent object in a persistent context AND you have the cascade established on the parent object to the child, Hibernate should handle this automatically for you, updating/creating the appropriate changes where necessary for your child object saying you use a saveOrUpdate from the parent.